# Return only one row from Oracle SQL, using outer join and case statement

Tags: oracle, case

I'm trying to figure out how to just return one row per result, even if there are multiple activities ('act's) per result. I've read and searched to no avail.

What I want:

```
Date       Site Result act1 act2

1985-06-10 1008 NT6    5    10
```

What I get:

```
Date       Site Result act1 act2

1985-06-10 1008 NT6    5    
1985-06-10 1008 NT6         10
```

Here's my (example) code, which I know is not broken, but it's the path I tried. I just don't know how to obtain what I want.

```
SELECT
t."Date",
t."Site",
t."Result",
CASE
  WHEN a.Type = 'act1'
  THEN a.Count
END AS "act1",
CASE
  WHEN a.Type = 'act2'
  THEN a.Count
END AS "act2"
FROM   
(
SELECT Sample.SAMPLE_ID,
       Sample.Date,
       Sample.Site,
       Sample.Result    
FROM   Sample
WHERE  Sample.Date is Between then and now
) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN
ACTIVITY
ON (ACTIVITY.SAMPLE_ID = t.SAMPLE_ID)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

```
select t."Date", t."Site", t."Result",
        sum(case when a.Type = 'act1' then a.Count else 0 end ) AS act1,
        sum(case when a.Type = 'act2' then a.Count else 0 end ) AS act2
from   sample left outer join activity
        on (activity.sample_id = t.sample_id)
where  sample.date is between then and now
```

and don't use braces on column names.